# GWT compiled code causes NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt

I am parsing a string, character by character.  The string size is around 1 million characters.  This seems to take three or four seconds on Chrome and IE9.  However on Firefox, it hangs for about a minute and then throws a NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY error.  Firefox seems to have a hard time with GWT's compiled javascript.  Is there a way to fix this and/or speed this up?

Comment: Obviously no way to help you if you don't provide any code.

Comment: As Strelok says, seeing the actual code would help.  For one thing, it could be profiled to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the memory of JVM when you are working in Development Mode.

Development Mode will be always slower than Production Mode because of the required overhead of marshaling and unmarshaling Java objects into Javascript and vice versa.

So, i think if u launch the app is production mode, you can find a better solution.

Comment: You Can Also refer this link http://superuser.com/questions/104907/firefox-temporarily-freezing-on-most-web-page-load-ns-error-out-of-memory

Comment: I am running in Production Mode, not in Development Mode.